# Splitting fields of $X^n-c$ and radical extensions

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

This nice Quora forum gives an intuition behind radical extensions and solvability:

[How does Galois theory relate to the solvability of polynomial equations?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Galois-theory-relate-to-the-solvability-of-polynomial-equations)

However, I am looking for formal proof of this sentence:

This generalizes: the roots of any rational polynomial are expressible in radicals if and only if its corresponding splitting field sits inside of a subfield obtained by taking splitting fields of polynomials of the form $X^n-c$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following the defintion from "Topics in Field Theory" by (G. Karpilovsky) page 421 Chapter 8:

We say that $E/F$ is *a radical field extension* if $E$ is of the form $E = F(\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_m)$ with $\lambda_1^{n_1}\in F$ and $\lambda_i^{n_i}\in F(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_{i-1})$ for $2\leq i\leq m$ and $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$.

We see that a radical extension is a successive extension over $F$ via polynomials of the form $X^n - c$.

Take Taking $F = \mathbb{Q}$, your statement "the roots of any rational polynomial are expressible in radicals" means that the roots of this polynomial lie in some radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since every radical extension $E/\mathbb{Q}$ are successive extensions via polynomials of the form $X^n - c$, then ofcourse $E$ sits inside the splitting field of all of these polynomials.

Comment: Actually, my question is on the motivation for this definition of radical field extension based on the book you mentioned. If you look into the link, the person says, "No. Consider the splitting field of  $^3−3+1$. There is only one subfield that it contains, which is the rational numbers, and there is no  $,$ such that this is the splitting field of  $^−$." How does this definition validate this statement?
 .